# how to edit a wordpress theme background?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have wordpress installed on my system. I am using twentyten theme, in the theme directory there is style.css file. In that file I tried

```
body {
       background-color: red;
}
```

but nothing happens, no matter what change in style.css it does not reflects in browser.
Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the right style sheet? Do you see your changes in your browser when you go to "View Source" and open the style sheet manually? Are you doing this before any other `body` blocks?

Comment: Did you try to modify any other theme? Because Twenty-ten is made of multiple opaque DIVS. These divs are preventing you to see the RED background.

Comment: I just noticed that after changing the style.css file and deleting the cache, if I select view source then I dont see the changes in the style.css file. But I am damn sure that I am editing the right file. Now this is strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you cleared your browser's cache? Often the browser will cache the css files to be more efficient, so any changes you make to it require you to clear the cache.

If you're using a windows machine: `ctrl + shift + del` should bring up the clear cache dialog

**Edit**: it appears that your css was in the `@media print` section of the stylesheet - which only applies to printed material

Comment: @Harbhag - are you sure that you're editing the appropriate stylesheet? is there another stylesheet overwriting your stylesheet? what about marking your change as `body{background-color:red !important;}` so that you value is taken over any other stylesheet (assuming they don't use `!important` too?

Comment: @Brett I just tried your suggestion but it does not seem to work as well.

Comment: @Harbhag - is your style sheet actually getting loaded? are you editing the proper stylesheet? Some projects will have multiple stylesheets floating around...

Comment: Yes I am editing the proper stylesheet, I can confirm this after viewing source of the page. There is just one stylesheet getting loaded and thats the one I am editing. Seems like some function is ignoring all my changes because when I change the stylesheet and then view it in source using browser I cant see the changes I made.

Comment: @Harbhag - you're saying that if you view the source of the stylesheet, your changes aren't reflected in that stylesheet?

Comment: @Harbhag - you put your CSS into the `@media print` section, which only applies when printing. Move it out of there and it should work just fine!

Comment: I added the changes to the end of the file but no effect. I even deleted everything and its empty now, still nothing happens. This is driving me nuts. Here is the output of view source from browser http://dpaste.com/hold/549224/

Comment: @Harbhag - well, you understand that your viewsource shouldn't look any different for the html page, right? Just the styles applied to it in the browser's view?

Comment: Ok its working now. I deleted the google-chrome folder from the /home/.config directory. Everything restarted.

Comment: @Harbhag - you need the #wrapper element to change the color of the middle of the middle of the page, the outside is blue: `#wrapper { background:blue !important;}`

Comment: Yes I just figured that out. Thanks

Comment: Guess what, its my first day with css.

Comment: @Harbhag - there's a lot to learn, but once you get the hang of some of the nuances, it shouldn't be too bad!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to figure this stuff out is to install Firebug in Firefox or use the built-in Inspector in Chrome.

Right-click on the page, do 'Inspect Element' and check what the Inspector tells you. Probably the background-color you're setting is being overruled by another style rule (Inspector will tell you this) or there are other elements with another background-color which are placed on top of the body, thus hiding the red background-color.

Either way, doing an 'Inspect Element' will make this clear. We can only guess from here.

Comment: I have already tried that. But the changes does not reflect. I am always use firebug in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ensure that you're editing the right style sheet. For example try to erase all the styling code inside this file and refresh your website. If you loose your style then you're in the right place.

Second try to use Firebug Addon it will help you to inspect the html Element then you can show the corresponding CSS for this element. you can change whatever you want and see the effects directly on your page then you can write these changes to the style sheet.
hope it helps you.

Comment: I am editing the proper stylesheet but deleting it does not effect anything. here is the style.css file http://dpaste.com/hold/549223/     and here is the output of view source http://dpaste.com/hold/549224/

Comment: @Harbhag I see in your html that the path for the style sheet is http://localhost/~harbhag/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css could you tell me why ~ before harbhag

Comment: Because I have installed wordpress in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that style is overwritten by another background attribute on the body a few lines below (browser will always render the last css attributes of elements). Something you can check easily with firebug.

If you have plugins, disable them just to be sure.

Other then that and the suggestions already made I'm not entirely sure what could cause this